# how to prevent fluentui/react Button from firing after a click?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, fluentui-react

I am using the button from fluentui/react (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/button) and I would like to put a condition on onClick event to prevent the event from firing if the condition is false.

I tried both `event.preventDefault()`; and `event.stopPropagation()`; but they did not work.

How can I prevent the onclick event from firing if the condition does not meet?

```
//The button is inside a child compoment.

const handleOnClick = async (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLDivElement | HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLSpanElement | BaseButton | Button, MouseEvent>) =>{         
event.stopPropagation();                                                            
event.preventDefault();
  ...
  }

<PrimaryButton onClick={(event) => handleOnClick(event)}>Save</PrimaryButton>
```

searched but found nothing that could help me in this particular example.